# CLSID_FileOpenDialog where is it in the registry? Is it comdlg32? ICommDlgBrowser? CIDopen? or something else?

Tags: windows, winapi, com, registry

I would like to create a custom common item dialog (CID) and then register my custom COM:

But I am confused about the CID COM object. I want to see the existing COM object before I make a custom one.

I found comdlg32 in the registry but I think that is the legacy (pre-Vista) dialog.
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{725F645B-EAED-4fc5-B1C5-D9AD0ACCBA5E}\InProcServer32
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{725F645B-EAED-4fc5-B1C5-D9AD0ACCBA5E}\InProcServer32

I found ICommDlgBrowser but that's an interface, not a COM?
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface{000214F1-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface{000214F1-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}

I thought the new one is CIDOpen, but I can't find a CLSID in the registry, rather this is what I find:
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1285309903-269343738-3178715341-1001\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CIDOpen

This is the documentation for customization: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/common-file-dialog but my question is about finding the CID COM object in the registry.

Comment: `CLSID_FileOpenDialog` has the GUID `DC1C5A9C-E88A-4dde-A5A1-60F82A20AEF7`.

Comment: And `CLSID_FileSaveDialog` is `C0B4E2F3-BA21-4773-8DBA-335EC946EB8B`

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide a link where I can find these myself?

Comment: There is no link.  Look in the definitions in the Win32 SDK.

Comment: This site has all guids and iids you can dream of: https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=CLSID_FileOpenDialog or the reverse way https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=725F645B-EAED-4fc5-B1C5-D9AD0ACCBA5E => `CLSID_FileOpenDialogLegacy` . ICommDlgBrowser  is indeed an interface, not a "coclass" ("a COM" means nothing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IFileDialog` has a GUID value of `42F85136-DB7E-439C-85F1-E4075D135FC8`. In the Registry, it looks like:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{42F85136-DB7E-439C-85F1-E4075D135FC8}
(Default): "IFileDialog"

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{42F85136-DB7E-439C-85F1-E4075D135FC8}\NumMethods
(Default): "27"

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{42F85136-DB7E-439C-85F1-E4075D135FC8}\ProxyStubClsid32
(Default): "{C90250F3-4D7D-4991-9B69-A5C5BC1C2AE6}"
```

`IFileDialogEvents` has a GUID value of `973510DB-7D7F-452B-8975-74A85828D354`. In the Registry, it looks like:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{973510DB-7D7F-452B-8975-74A85828D354}
(Default): "IFileDialogEvents"

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{973510DB-7D7F-452B-8975-74A85828D354}\NumMethods
(Default): "10"

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{973510DB-7D7F-452B-8975-74A85828D354}\ProxyStubClsid32
(Default): "{C90250F3-4D7D-4991-9B69-A5C5BC1C2AE6}"
```

`CLSID_FileOpenDialog` has a GUID value of `DC1C5A9C-E88A-4dde-A5A1-60F82A20AEF7`. In the Registry, it looks like:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{DC1C5A9C-E88A-4dde-A5A1-60F82A20AEF7}
(Default): "File Open Dialog"

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{DC1C5A9C-E88A-4dde-A5A1-60F82A20AEF7}\InProcServer32
(Default): "%SystemRoot%\System32\comdlg32.dll"
ThreadingModel: "Apartment"
```

`IFileOpenDialog` has a GUID value of `D57C7288-D4AD-4768-BE02-9D969532D960`. In the Registry, it looks like:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{D57C7288-D4AD-4768-BE02-9D969532D960}
(Default): "IFileOpenDialog"

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{D57C7288-D4AD-4768-BE02-9D969532D960}\NumMethods
(Default): "29"

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{D57C7288-D4AD-4768-BE02-9D969532D960}\ProxyStubClsid32
(Default): "{C90250F3-4D7D-4991-9B69-A5C5BC1C2AE6}"
```

`CLSID_FileSaveDialog` has a GUID value of `C0B4E2F3-BA21-4773-8DBA-335EC946EB8B`. In the Registry, it looks like:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C0B4E2F3-BA21-4773-8DBA-335EC946EB8B}
(Default): "File Save Dialog"

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C0B4E2F3-BA21-4773-8DBA-335EC946EB8B}\InProcServer32
(Default): "%SystemRoot%\System32\comdlg32.dll"
ThreadingModel: "Apartment"
```

`IFileSaveDialog` has a GUID value of `84BCCD23-5FDE-4CDB-AEA4-AF64B83D78AB`. In the Registry, it looks like:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{84BCCD23-5FDE-4CDB-AEA4-AF64B83D78AB}
(Default): "IFileSaveDialog"

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{84BCCD23-5FDE-4CDB-AEA4-AF64B83D78AB}\NumMethods
(Default): "32"

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{84BCCD23-5FDE-4CDB-AEA4-AF64B83D78AB}\ProxyStubClsid32
(Default): "{C90250F3-4D7D-4991-9B69-A5C5BC1C2AE6}"
```